# Don't let the user add info in a form field, without being disabled

Tags: javascript

I'm using 2 input fields as a calendar. So when the user clicks a modal with a calendar opens and the user can select a date. The date is then thru Javascript added.

But the user can ignore the calendar, and paste a date in the input field, which can create validation errors.

Can I prevent the user completing the input field directly, without using disabled on the input HTML?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Forcing people to use calendar widgets instead of just typing or pasting a date is a horrible UI experience. Find a better way to solve the problem. Like validating their input with JS and/or having a smarter parser that can cope with different date formats.

Comment: Disable pasting text into input: `onpaste="return false;"`

Comment: Could you use a `input type="date"`...? These show a native calendar and users cannot paste data in.

Comment: Just stick a `readonly` attribute on it if you *must*, but really you should accept any date string and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @Stuart, not really because I need to use older browsers, but I need to respect a specific design

Comment: @Quentin - I have a specific validation on backend also, even if I let using multiple formats in javascript, it will be invalidated in backend, where I have more limited choices, just one format

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault()` for `input` (or maybe `change`) event handler.

```js
dateInput.addEventListener('input', function(ev){
    //validate date format
    if (newValueIsNotValid) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("datepicker").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var dateValue = this.value;
  var regex = new RegExp(/^\s*(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])\.(1[012]|0?[1-9])\.((?:19|20)\d{2})\s*$/g);
  if (!regex.test(dateValue) && dateValue !== "") {
    this.classList.add("error");
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("error");
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: solid 3px red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="datepicker" onpaste="return false;" />
```